# Remove all animations from Ubuntu

Tags: unity, 17.04

I have an old server with plenty of cores and RAM, but a very poor GPU. Which is working fine, apart from a lot of lag when switching windows etc. I have been trying to tweak it with unity-tweak-tool, e.g. turning off window animation and window spread, but its not working.

So, to clarify: I want to turn of all animations in Ubuntu.

PS: i tried to put in a variety of GPUs, but it doesnt play well with the machine.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is past its end-of-life, and is no longer supported on this site. Please upgrade to 17.10.1 to continue to receive support, including security updates.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex This question actually have a cross-release solution. Also read: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13837/reminder-questions-on-eol-releases-are-not-off-topic-simply-because-theyre-eol

Comment: You may find that just turning off the animations may not bring much of a performace improvement - in that case you should try one of the lighter desktop environments, such as MATE or XFCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is the applicable one, for me on 16.04. It should work too on the latest release.

You can install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and disable animations right away. You can take a look at the application and disable anything you don't need.

I don't have an idea which one should be disabled, but there should be options which control animation (including tab switch, maximize/minimize, etc.).

[image: CCSM]

Comment: @MikaelS Don't forget to tick mark the answer to accept the answer, if you think this answer solves your problem. More info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

**For Ubuntu 18.04:**

```
android@android:~$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open gnome-tweak tool and disable **animation**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (since this is a server) would be to use a server release without a DE (Desktop Environment) If your running in text mode you don't need to concern yourself much with GPU performance. This should apply to any version of Ubuntu, past, current, and future.